# Debug/Handle Java/Restlet application SEGFAULT

Tags: java, web-services, segmentation-fault, monitor, restlet

I have a application service use Restlet framework. But after running 1-2 days. I caught it stopped unexpected. Checked the application directory, I found a log file said:

> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #
>
> ## SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000039c7e7adfe, pid=32765, tid=1077344576

Log file here: http://pastebin.com/fwNKWdT6

So can anyone show me how to debug or handle this? I know Linux application can catch SEGFAULT signal and manually restart. Is there anyway in java application to do that?

Also, do you guys know how to monitor CPU/memory of remote java application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the native parts of JRE code (Zip handling?). You should first try to upgrade to JDK 7.0 update 4 and then report the bug to Oracle.

For remote monitoring, you can use VisualVM part of JDK:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html